# SQL Server - Merging/Grouping contiguous timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (RECORDS) with records from when to when items were linked to a parent item:

```
CHILD   STARTDATE                  ENDDATE                     PARENT
207     2013-12-18 12:45:59.017    2014-01-09 18:16:01.227     NULL
207     2014-01-09 18:16:01.227    2016-03-03 09:54:28.757     NULL
207     2016-03-03 09:54:28.757    2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     NULL
10558   2016-03-03 18:10:34.877    2016-04-05 10:25:22.860     10557
10558   2016-04-05 10:25:22.860    2016-04-05 11:33:10.493     10557
10558   2016-04-05 11:33:10.493    2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     10557
10596   2016-05-15 16:55:15.970    2016-05-16 10:00:00.000     10592
10596   2016-05-16 10:00:00.000    2016-05-17 10:00:00.000     10593
10596   2016-05-17 10:00:00.000    2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     10592
10600   2012-12-18 12:45:59.017    2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     10599
```

I displayed above the 4 main cases:
For the same child, new records with null value (207)
For the same child, new records with the same parent value (10558)
For the same child, new records with a parent change (10596)
For the same child, only one record (10600).

As child items can change back to an older parent, using :

```
SELECT 
  CHILD 
, MIN(STARTDATE) as STARTDATE
, MAX(ENDDATE) as ENDDATE
, PARENT 
FROM RECORDS
GROUP BY CHILD, PARENT
```

Would result in the following undesired result for item 10596:

```
207     2013-12-18 12:45:59.017     2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     NULL
10558   2016-03-03 18:10:34.877     2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     10557
10596   2016-05-15 16:55:15.970     2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     10592
10596   2016-05-16 10:00:00.000     2016-05-17 10:00:00.000     10593
10600   2012-12-18 12:45:59.017     2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     10599
```

The desired result would be :

```
207     2013-12-18 12:45:59.017     2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     NULL
10558   2016-03-03 18:10:34.877     2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     10557
10596   2016-05-15 16:55:15.970     2016-05-16 10:00:00.000     10592
10596   2016-05-16 10:00:00.000     2016-05-17 10:00:00.000     10593
10596   2016-05-17 10:00:00.000     2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     10592
10600   2012-12-18 12:45:59.017     2100-01-01 00:00:00.000     10599
```

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that there is continuity (no overlaps) in your records:

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CHILD ORDER BY STARTDATE) r
    FROM RECORDS
)

,
cte2
AS
(
    SELECT
        t1.CHILD CHILD1
        , t1.STARTDATE STARTDATE1
        , t1.ENDDATE ENDDATE1
        , t1.PARENT PARENT1
        , t1.r r1
        , t2.CHILD CHILD2
        , t2.STARTDATE STARTDATE2
        , t2.ENDDATE ENDDATE2
        , t2.PARENT PARENT2
        , t2.r r2
    FROM
        cte t1
        LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON
            t1.CHILD = t2.CHILD
            AND t1.r = t2.r - 1
    WHERE
        t1.PARENT != t2.PARENT
        OR (t1.PARENT IS NULL AND t2.PARENT IS NOT NULL)
        OR (t2.PARENT IS NULL AND t1.PARENT IS NOT NULL)
        OR t2.r IS NULL
)

SELECT
    CHILD1 CHILD
    ,
        ISNULL
            (
                (
                    SELECT MIN(STARTDATE)
                    FROM RECORDS
                    WHERE
                        CHILD = CHILD1
                        AND (PARENT = PARENT1 OR (PARENT IS NULL AND PARENT1 IS NULL))
                        AND STARTDATE >=
                            (
                                SELECT ENDDATE1
                                FROM cte2 cte2INNER
                                WHERE
                                    cte2INNER.CHILD1 = cte2OUTER.CHILD1
                                    AND cte2INNER.r2 =
                                        (
                                            SELECT MAX(cteINNER2.r2)
                                            FROM cte2 cteINNER2
                                            WHERE
                                                cteINNER2.CHILD1 = cte2OUTER.CHILD1
                                                AND cteINNER2.r2 <= cte2OUTER.r1
                                        )
                            )
                )
                ,
                    (
                        SELECT MIN(STARTDATE)
                        FROM RECORDS
                        WHERE CHILD = CHILD1
                    )
            )
            STARTDATE
    , ENDDATE1 ENDDATE
    , PARENT1 PARENT
FROM cte2 cte2OUTER
```

It runs quickly with a temp table:

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CHILD ORDER BY STARTDATE) r
    FROM RECORDS
)


SELECT
    t1.CHILD CHILD1
    , t1.STARTDATE STARTDATE1
    , t1.ENDDATE ENDDATE1
    , t1.PARENT PARENT1
    , t1.r r1
    , t2.CHILD CHILD2
    , t2.STARTDATE STARTDATE2
    , t2.ENDDATE ENDDATE2
    , t2.PARENT PARENT2
    , t2.r r2
INTO #RECORDSTEMP
FROM
    cte t1
    LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON
        t1.CHILD = t2.CHILD
        AND t1.r = t2.r - 1
WHERE
    t1.PARENT != t2.PARENT
    OR (t1.PARENT IS NULL AND t2.PARENT IS NOT NULL)
    OR (t2.PARENT IS NULL AND t1.PARENT IS NOT NULL)
    OR t2.r IS NULL

SELECT
    CHILD1 CHILD
    ,
        ISNULL
            (
                (
                    SELECT MIN(STARTDATE)
                    FROM RECORDS
                    WHERE
                        CHILD = CHILD1
                        AND (PARENT = PARENT1 OR (PARENT IS NULL AND PARENT1 IS NULL))
                        AND STARTDATE >=
                            (
                                SELECT ENDDATE1
                                FROM #RECORDSTEMP rtmpINNER
                                WHERE
                                    rtmpINNER.CHILD1 = rtmpOUTER.CHILD1
                                    AND rtmpINNER.r2 =
                                        (
                                            SELECT MAX(rtmpINNER2.r2)
                                            FROM #RECORDSTEMP rtmpINNER2
                                            WHERE
                                                rtmpINNER2.CHILD1 = rtmpOUTER.CHILD1
                                                AND rtmpINNER2.r2 <= rtmpOUTER.r1
                                        )
                            )
                )
                ,
                    (
                        SELECT MIN(STARTDATE)
                        FROM RECORDS
                        WHERE CHILD = CHILD1
                    )
            )
            STARTDATE
    , ENDDATE1 ENDDATE
    , PARENT1 PARENT
FROM #RECORDSTEMP rtmpOUTER

DROP TABLE #RECORDSTEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, it works.

I also received this solution:

```
WITH DISTINCTRECORDS as (
                SELECT 
                CHILD
                , 
                CASE
                WHEN
                (
                    CHILD = lag(CHILD) over(order by CHILD,STARTDATE, ENDDATE, PARENT) 
                    AND
                    STARTDATE = lag(ENDDATE) over(order by CHILD,STARTDATE, ENDDATE, PARENT) 
                    AND
                    (PARENT = lag(PARENT) over(order by CHILD,STARTDATE, ENDDATE, PARENT) OR ( PARENT is null AND lag(PARENT) over(order by CHILD,STARTDATE, ENDDATE, PARENT) is null  ))
                )
                    OR
                (
                    CHILD = lead(CHILD) over(order by CHILD,STARTDATE, ENDDATE, PARENT) 
                    AND
                    ENDDATE = lead(STARTDATE) over(order by CHILD,STARTDATE, ENDDATE, PARENT) 
                    AND
                    (PARENT = lead(PARENT) over(order by CHILD,STARTDATE, ENDDATE, PARENT) OR ( PARENT is null AND lead(PARENT) over(order by CHILD,STARTDATE, ENDDATE, PARENT) is null  ))
                )
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END ToBeMerged
                ,   STARTDATE
                ,   ENDDATE
                ,   PARENT 

                FROM RECORDS
)

SELECT CHILD, min(STARTDATE) STARTDATE, max(ENDDATE) ENDDATE, PARENT FROM DISTINCTRECORDS WHERE ToBeMerged = 1 GROUP BY CHILD, PARENT
UNION ALL
SELECT CHILD, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, PARENT FROM DISTINCTRECORDS WHERE ToBeMerged = 0
```

Which one would have the best performance ?

Comment: The query you've posted here runs much quicker (I'd never heard of these LAG and LEAD functions!). I also think you can remove the STARTDATE and ENDDATE clauses, as the data is already being ordered in the CHILD and PARENT checks (unless you are specifically looking to tie records together by matching end (previous record) and start (current record) timestamps, and any gap in time would indicate a new record.

Comment: Actually, this query is not working if there are two groups with the same parent and more than one record - it groups them all together.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: If it is like this - CHILD: 207; PARENT SEQUENCE: 30-30-30-45-30-30-30; all of the 30s are 'ToBeMerged' so will be grouped together as one record.